# I am using tkinter to create quiz in python, but when i try to get the score, it does not give me the score

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a basic quiz using tkinter in python. I want to show the user the score they got at the end of the quiz but currently, the score is only showing 0. Here is the code

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import random
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
global score
score = 0
global count
count = 0
root = Tk()
root.title('Quiz')
root.config(bg = 'white')
root.geometry('770x555')

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, correct_ans):
        self.question = question
        self.correct_ans = correct_ans


def ask_quit():
    if tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "The quiz has finished now, would you like to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

def checkResult(letter):
    global score
    if letter == currentQuestion.correct_ans:
        score += 1
    if not len(questions) == 0:
        getNewQuestion()
    else:
        result()
        ask_quit()

def getNewQuestion():
    global count
    global currentQuestion
    currentQuestion = questions.pop()
    for i, var in enumerate((titleVar, aVar, bVar, cVar, dVar)):
        var.set(currentQuestion.question[i])
    count+= 1

def result():
    global score
    print('result:', score)

def buttons():
    question = Label(root, textvariable=titleVar)
    question.pack()

    A = Button(root, textvariable = aVar, command = lambda: checkResult('A'))
    A.pack()

    B = Button(root, textvariable = bVar, command = lambda: checkResult('B'))
    B.pack()

    C = Button(root, textvariable = cVar, command = lambda: checkResult('C'))
    C.pack()

    D = Button(root, textvariable = dVar, command = lambda: checkResult('D'))
    D.pack()

file_handle = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "easyquestion.csv") 
count = 0
score = 0

questions = []

with open('easyquestion.csv', 'r') as file_handle:
    # list_question = []
    displayQ = []
    for line in file_handle:
        line_sections = line.split(",")
        displayQ = line_sections[:-1]
        correct_ans = line_sections[-1]
        questions.append(Question(displayQ, correct_ans))

titleVar = StringVar()
aVar = StringVar()
bVar = StringVar()
cVar = StringVar()
dVar = StringVar()

currentQuestion = None
getNewQuestion()

canvas = Canvas(width = 100, height = 100, bg = 'black')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "/Users/arjyo/Downloads/image.png")
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)

buttons()

root.mainloop()
```

you will also need a .csv file in the same folder called "easyquestion.csv".
this is what it should look like

```
what is the smallest country in the world?,a) Monaco,b) Vatican City,c)Luxembourg,d)Maldives,B
what is the largest country in the world?,a)Russia,b)USA,c)India,d)China,A
what is the largest continent in the world?,a)Europe,b)Africa,c)Asia,d)Australia,C
When did world war 2 start?,a)1945,b)1942,c)1918,d)1939,D
What did Isaac newton discover?,a)electricity,b)gravity,c)energy,d)magnetism,B
what is the scientific name for humans?,a)hetero sapians,b)homo sapiens,c)homo exodus,d)hetero exodus,B
what is the boiling pont of water?,a)110 degree C,b)373 degree C,c)100 deegre C,d)0 degree C,C
What is 2*3*4*5*0+7-4?,a)123,b)27,c)3,d)9,C
Who owns microsoft?,a)Google,b)apple,c)Microsoft,d) ubuntu,C
what is the denary value of: 01001111,a)64,b)70,c)15,d)79,D
```

I am attempting to print out the score and then have it appear in a messagebox to show at the end of the quiz. If you have any advice on how to improve the code feel free to share. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the input line when reading from csv file:

```
line_sections = line.strip().split(",")
```

Otherwise, the `Question.correct_ans` will have a '\n' at the end and the comparison inside `checkResult()` will fail.